# Prove that the following context-free grammar does not generate the language by finding a word of the language that is not generated by the grammar.

Tags: computer-science, formal-languages, context-free-grammar

Here is the language:

> $\{w \in $ {$0,1$}$^* \mid w$ has 2 to 3 times more $0$ than $1$,
>   inclusively$\}$

The following grammar does not generate such language.
Prove it by finding a word of the language that is not generated by the grammar.

> $S \rightarrow\varepsilon $
>
> $| 001S | 00S1 | 0S01 | S001  $
>
> $| 010S | 01S0 | 0S10 | S010  $
>
> $| 100S | 10S0 | 1S00 | S100  $
>
> $| 0001S | 000S1 | 00S01 | 0S001 | S0001  $
>
> $| 0010S | 001S0 | 00S10 | 0S010 | S0010 $
>
> $| 0100S | 010S0 | 01S00 | 0S100 | S0100 $
>
> $| 1000S| 100S0| 10S00| 1S000|S1000  $

The grammar clearly always respects the condition that there is always 2 to 3 times more $0$ than $1$, inclusively.

In every case, there is either 2 "$0$" and 1 "$1$" OR 3 "$0$" and 1 "$1$".

So for 100 "$1$", I can have 200 to 300 "$0$", which is what we want.

I can have words starting with only "$1$"s and ending with "$0$" with $|1S000|$ and $|1S00|$. The reverse can be done with $|000S1|$ and $|00S1|$.

The other cases can be used to alternate "$1$"s and "$0$"s in the word.

So I really can't think of a word in the language that the grammar can't generate!

Any help appreciated!

Comment: I haven't seen this notation before.  Does $|001S|00S1|0S01|S001$ denote four four-character strings, any of which can be substituted for $S$ (that is four productions) or does it mean something else?

Comment: @saulspatz $0$ and $1$ are terminals, $S$ is a nonterminal that can be substituted by anything between $|$ and $|$. And yes, that was a typo. Thanks!

Comment: $S$ can become $001S$ or $00S1$ or .... $S1000$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This grammar is incapable of generating any word that both starts and ends with 0000.  Pick any word of the language that satisfies this constraint: there are plenty to choose from of many different lengths.

Answer (score 0):

Any substitution adds $3$ or $4$ terminals to the string, so if a string generated by the grammar is $16$ characters long, it must be formed by substituting $4$ of the last $20$ strings, since the only solution of $3s+4t=16$ in nonnegative integers is $(s,t)=(0,4)$  Thus, any such string will contain exactly $4$ ones.  Thus, any $16-$bit string with exactly $5$ ones is a string in the language that cannot be generated by the grammar.